# Sandbox key offered to the API with no sandbox endpoint

Tags: python, python-requests

```
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

>>> url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/login'
>>> user = 'Jlu4IelEtiaq8moJkJKgQFDxofEa' # sandbox consumer key
>>> pw = '<actual sandbox consumer secret>' # sandbox consumer secret
>>> data = 'grant_type=password&username=<myemail address>&password=<my stubhub pw>'
>>> r = requests.post( url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth( user, pw ), data = data, headers=headers )
>>> cookies = r.cookies

>>> cookies
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='DC', value='origin11', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.stubhub.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1422551776,  discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>


>>> r.text
'{"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":14893480,"refresh_token":"8ac59f47c270dfa460536d115bb05279"    ,"access_token":"7d17d4d5a1388ec755f8fd17cff9d04b"}'
```

So far so good I am able to login using the API and get an access token, the problem I am encountering happens when I try to get a list of the tickets for an event. https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/doc-viewer.jag?category=Search&api=InventorySearchAPI&endpoint=searchinventory&version=v1

```
>>> r = requests.get( 'https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v1?eventid=9107490', cookies=cookies, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ZjjHxrtrcYVDE39MVGPcfIR0OJca'})

>>> r.text
'<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>900901</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Sandbox key offered to the API with no sandbox endpoint</am:description></am:fault>'
```

Requests have been tried using the Application Token in my Sandbox and the access_token received logging in and if fails both ways. Any help would be appreciated this is really driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem that was generating this error. I looked into what an endpoint is, an endpoint is the API method or function that is being used and a little further searching showed me that when accessing the sandbox the api domain is https://api.stubhubsandbox.com/

After eliminating the error I started getting a different error.

```
site is not available since below pool is down
```

So I moved out of the sandbox to Production and everything is working now.

Comment: "After eliminating the error I started getting a different error." but how did you eliminated first error? You have marked it answer but it does not contain the answer to your original question?

Comment: I eleminated the first error by changing the url parameter to https://api.stubhubsandbox.com/

Comment: please edit your answer and add the last comments into answer to make the answer understandable.